# How to get Drupal Rules settings?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-rules

How to programmatically retrieve configuration of the specific rule?

I tried

`$settings = rules_config_load('RULE_NAME');`

It returns very basic info (name, ID etc) and empty "settings" array.

Cant also get it directly from DB .

It is stored in serialized array that can not be fully processed with the 
`unserialize()` function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the same issue and end up here, here is a solution i found, you need to call actions() on your rule to access settings:

```
$rule = rules_config_load('RULE_NAME');
foreach ($rule->actions() as $action) {
  $settings[] = $action->settings;
}
```